# Why doesn't logstash grab or index the files from the mapped drive?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I don't understand why logstash is so finicky with network resources. I shared a folder on another machine and then mapped it as Z: under Windows Explorer. I've verified the path and everything. I can get logstash (with ELK stack) to input local files but it just doesn't seem to do anything with network or mapped resources.

Is there something insanely simple I'm missing here? Do I need additional arguments for outputting mapped drive inputs to elasticsearch?

```
input { 
file {
  type => "BbLog"
  path => "Z:/*"
}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
  }
}
```

Comment: Windows services don't see drive mappings. Make sure the service is running as an account with network access (ex NetworkService or LocalSystem) and use an UNC path.

Comment: What is the correct UNC path syntax for the input for logstash? is it standard backward escapes or does it use forward slashes? \\server\folder or //server/folder?

Comment: Can use forward slash: `//server/share/path/*`, if the files are in the root directory of the share `//server/share/*`. This is because the Windows API also supports forward-slashes in both local path names and UNC names.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604061/configuring-logstash-on-windows) found a possible answer, try setting your path to something like:

```
path => "z:/**/*.log"
```

Obviously you would want to edit that to fit your configuration, use double * as your wildcards for expansion. I would suggest that starting logstash up asking it to read everything off a network drive probably isn't the best idea, by [default the file input will try to expand wildcard globs every 15 seconds](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file#discover_interval), so it might never finish expanding before starting again.

I can't say I have ever used logstash on Windows, but I know there are a few issues when people do, these are probably documented on the github pages if you go and have a dig. Failing that the #logstash irc channel on freenode is almost always quite active.